# Sample size calculation for the rate of infections between two groups

Tags: sample-size, poisson-distribution

I am in the progress of calculating the sample size for a treated/untreated group comparison.

The data provided is a mean infection rate (mean/100 years) of a literature recherche.

Assuming the infections are poisson distributed. So the SD=sqrt(mean).

The alternative hypothesis would be: Treatment lowers the rate of infection.

I am using sas to do all calculations.

```
proc power; 
    twosamplemeans test=diff_satt
    groupmeans = 0.05 | 0.025
    GROUPSTDDEV = 0.224 | 0.158
    power = .1 to .8 by 0.1
    ntotal = .
    sides=l;
run;
```

Are my assumptions and procedures correct?

BR
Lukas

Comment: I have doubts about this. I think `twosamplemeans` assumes normality, whereas you have count data.

Comment: For sample size calculations you need to propose a *quantitative* alternative hypothesis.  "lowers the rate" doesn't give you any usable information.  The sample size will also depend on the background infection rate: after all, the smaller the rate is, the more people you will have to select in order to observe any infections at all.

Comment: I do not use SAS but is there not an option for comparing rates rather than means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Robert Long and @mdewey a comparison in means would not be valid for a poisson distributed proportion.

Hence I moved to the twosamplefreq method which is the calculation for a chi-square test.

@whuber: Since I did not receive any expected outcome for the treatment group I simulated five scenarios.

```
proc power;
twosamplefreq
  groupproportions = 0.05 | 0.01 to 0.03 by 0.005
  sides=L
  alpha=0.025
  power=.
  NTotal=50 to 1000;
run;
```

Comment: Was this intended as an answer or as a modification to the question?